How many ID questions were deleted by a moderator since the February 2018 ID question mass deletion?
In recent meta discussions about restoring previously closed and deleted ID questions: Please unlock, undelete, & reopen closed ID questions in line with our community consensus and Which closed/deleted/locked ID questions should be reopened/undeleted/unlocked?, some users have expressed concern about the potential volume of questions that might return if we undelete ID questions closed and deleted after the February 2018 ID question mass deletion.
One particularly thoughtful concern came from Randal'Thor:

[It's] a bit worrying to think about going through thousands of questions to apply those standards, if everything from 2018-24 gets undeleted for the community to vote on. [...] I wonder if there's any way to know how many (non-spam/abusive) ID questions were deleted in those 6 years - are we talking hundreds, thousands, ... ?

Based on our site's question volume in recent years, I believe the actual number of affected questions is much smaller—likely dozens, or at most a few hundred moderator-deleted ID questions. This seems quite manageable for our community to review, especially since some would likely be re-deleted automatically by the system's automated cleanup scripts (Roomba).
However, since regular users cannot search through other users' deleted questions, I cannot verify this estimate. So I'm asking our moderator team (and/or the Community Managers if needed), who have access to the necessary tools:
How many ID questions were manually deleted by a moderator after the February 2018 ID purge? Please include only questions closed for being ID questions, and include cases where a moderator was one of multiple delete voters. Please exclude questions deleted via spam/abusive flags and those automatically deleted by the Community user (Roomba).
The reason I'm focusing on moderator-deleted ID questions is because these deletions lock out community participation entirely. Once a moderator deletes a question, regular users cannot vote to undelete it. This limitation, combined with other restrictions (users can't search for deleted questions except their own, sub-10K rep users can't view deleted posts, and there's no undelete review queue), effectively prevents the community from participating in the review process for these questions.
This information will help the community better assess the scope of the proposed ID question restoration effort.

Great question, not sure why it was downvoted. (In case people think this is some kind of attack on moderators: the reason for asking specifically about questions deleted by a moderator is that those can't be effectively moderated by anyone else, as non-mods can't vote to undelete after a diamond deletion.)

@Randal'Thor Thanks for bringing that up, I should've mentioned that non-mods can't vote to undelete mod-deleted questions.

I'd be happy to help but honestly this goes beyond my abilities to query the stackexchange query engine.  Even simpler versions of this query are beyond my ability to work the tools.

@iandotkelly I appreciate your willingness to help. I'll reach out to the Community Managers to see if they can provide this information.

I looked into this, and there is a total of 451 questions that were closed with (some variant of) the "Identification questions are off-topic" after February 7, 2018, and subsequently unilaterally deleted by a moderator.
There are 233 other questions where a moderator cast the final deletion vote — for a total of 684 identification questions deleted by moderators, that had previously been closed as off-topic.

This is helpful! That seems like a reasonable number for the community to handle, especially considering the scale of the 2018 mass deletion (3,726 questions). Since only mods can undelete mod-deleted posts, users can't search for deleted questions except their own, and users below 10K rep can't view deleted questions; restoring them would give the community a chance to review them. This approach ensures that the process isn't entirely left to mods, making it more inclusive and transparent.
